# How to know, in validation(PL/SQL), if a page item is updated? Similar to apex.item().isChanged in JS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

In validation's PL/SQL,is there any way to get the status of a given page item to know if it is changed. Similar to the one in JS API, apex.item.isChanged()?

In the session information (accessed from the developer tools) we can see the status as "Updated" for page Items changed after rendering. How can we get that in the PLSQL in validations?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: What's your intent behind this functionality?

Comment: I am trying to secure disabled page items in the validations. If a disabled page item is changed from console,  in validation I am trying to reset it with the session value.

Comment: I thought session state protection handles this automatically. I'm normally prompted accordingly after changing disabled/hidden items using a DA, and not unprotected them.

Comment: Yes. But here diabling is done using JS (Client) and so it will not secure. Items are disabled based on conditions.

Answer (score 2):

if it is a database item, could you select it from the db and compare it to the value on the page? something like :

```
 declare 
    value varchar2(250);
 begin
    select your_column into value from your_table where id = :PAGE_ITEM_ID;
 if value != :PAGE_ITEM_VALUE then 
    /*do _something_here*/
 end if;
 end;
```

Comment: No. That's not an option. That item value is a result of a complex query and running it again would result in bad performance. We always have an option to store the values in a collection during rendering and compare them in validation. But i am wondering if there is something direct from APEX.

Comment: All that I can think of would be creating a hidden item, then setting this new item value with a dynamic action on page load to the value of the item you would like to validate, on validation compare the 2 items.

Comment: Test thoroughly, know the expected result of each test BEFORE hand, validate each test, capture and log all exceptions. When all that's done trust the database. If there no exception, then everything's ok. If you post validate the Update and that fails then whats wrong: the database failed to update, of the post-check is wrong?